# Multiple Join to single column using ID T-SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have following issue. I'm trying to join three tables:

TableA: Record_id, Reference_id, Param

TableB: Doc_id, NameB

TableC: Doc_id, NameC

depending on value in TableA.Param, I need to select Name from tables B or C by joining on Reference_id

I've tried to use "case" constrain, but didn't worked out :)

```
select  a.Record_id, a.Reference_id
       , case when Param = 'B' then b.NameB
              when Param = 'C' then c.NameC
from TableA as a inner join
     TableB as b on a.Reference_id = b.Doc_id inner join
     TableC as c on a.Reference_id = c.Doc_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use left-join instead, if you can post a sample data and the expected result  it will also help to help you with your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `left join` with that condition and take the first non-null name with `coalesce()`

```
select  a.Record_id, a.Reference_id,
        coalesce(b.NameB, c.NameC) as name
from TableA as a 
left join TableB as b on a.Reference_id = b.Doc_id 
                     and Param = 'B'
                     and b.STAT = 'A'
left join TableC as c on a.Reference_id = c.Doc_id 
                     and Param = 'C'
                     and c.STAT = 'A'
```

BTW your query was close (missed the `end`). This would have worked with `left join`s

```
select  a.Record_id, a.Reference_id,
        case when Param = 'B' then b.NameB
             when Param = 'C' then c.NameC
        end as name
from TableA as a 
left join TableB as b on a.Reference_id = b.Doc_id and b.STAT = 'A'
left join TableC as c on a.Reference_id = c.Doc_id and c.STAT = 'A'
```

Comment: That second version should probably also use left joins.

Comment: Yes, that is why I added the last sentence.

Comment: But I guess it is too misleading. Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: @juergend Yup, my query was also correct, but I've missed one more thing: Tables B and C has "Record Status Indicator" like 'A' - Actual and 'H' History, I need to get records that only has status 'A', when I use filter condition (where b.STAT = 'A' and c.STAT = 'A') result is empty, if I use where constrain only to one of table, then i see results, but these result related only to that specified table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Record_id, a.Reference_id, b.NameB AS Name
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.Reference_id = b.Doc_id 
WHERE a.Param = 'B'

UNION

SELECT a.Record_id, a.Reference_id, c.NameC AS Name
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableC as c ON a.Reference_id = c.Doc_id 
WHERE c.Param = 'C'
```

Comment: Do you have to rename NameB and NameC to get the union to work?

Comment: @mikeagg: The first query in a `union` defines the column names. In this case the last column is named `NameB`. An alias would be more clear like `... b.NameB as Name ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.Record_id, a.Reference_id,V.Name
FROM TableA AS a 
inner join
(
SELECT Doc_id id, NameB Name,'B' Type from TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT Doc_id ID, NameC name,'C' Type  From TableC
) AS V On V.ID=Reference_id AND Type=Param
```